# T-SQL RECURSION The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I try to find the distance between two members of the royal family tree (ex: between Queen Elizabeth II and Harry, Duke of Sussex, the distance will be 2)

When I run this query, I get an error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Query:

```
WITH ctv_genealogie(id1,id2,name1, name2, dist) AS
(
    -- initial query
    SELECT a.id, b.id, a.Name, b.Name, 1
    FROM RoyalPeople a
    JOIN AscDesc ON a.id = AscDesc.id_ascendent
    JOIN RoyalPeople b ON AscDesc.id_descendent = b.id

    UNION ALL

    -- recursive query
    SELECT a.id1,a.id2, a.name1, a.name2, dist+1
    FROM AscDesc 
    JOIN ctv_genealogie as a ON AscDesc.id_ascendent = a.id1 
                             AND AscDesc.id_descendent = a.id2
)
SELECT name1, name2, dist
FROM ctv_genealogie
WHERE dist = 2
```

This is the diagram:

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Either you have over 100 generations of the royal family (which I doubt) or you have cycles; i suspect the latter but this is very hard to know without any sample data.

Comment: If you load a Graph table you can use the SHORTEST_PATH function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

The maximum recursion is feature, that stops infinite/too-deep query.

More you can learn in official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15